# Create a Sharepoint site populated with default settings for an existing team project in TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Has Microsoft addressed the difficulty of creating a SP site *after* creating the Team Project in TFS 2012? I am aware of the [methods outlined here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/12/11/Configure-TFS-portal-afterwards-Beta-2.aspx), but I was hoping they had come up with something slicker in the new version. If not, does anybody know of a better method or tool than the one suggested in the previous link?

Answer (score 0):

The TFS Power Tools has a command `tfpt addprojectportal` that will create the SharePoint site for you after the Team Project has already been created. You will need to know process template that was used to create the team project. You will be able to find all the options you need for the command by using the `/?` switch.